# Ways to overcome sending email delay in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added a comment box and each time the user add new comment im calling an Insert Handler to apply this into the DB. What i like here is the quickness things done.

what i wanted to do now is to send each time a new comment inserted, WITHOUT DELAYS.

so i added **SmtpClient** and send the mail using **SendAsync** on the same Insert Handler.
that was not good enough for me, since even for the simplest email body ("hello world") it took it 5 seconds to repsonse!!! **Maybe I need to add a new thread?**

Is there any other way to overcome the delay of sending emails?
I thought to create a new Handler, that will run **onComplete** of the Insert Handler, that will call another Handler that will do the sending mail on the background, and the user will not notice. The problem with this may be Spam, but re-calling the same Handler over and over again.

Comment: Email transfer is inherently an asynchronous operation anyway - why does it matter *where* some delay is introduced?

Comment: This looks like premature optimization: a bunch of seconds of delay is to be expected when it comes to e-mail, they have to travel over the wire from sender to recipient anyway. A little network slowdown along the way is all it takes to make all the work you've done to overcome this "delay" useless. It's also worth pointing out that *clients* introduce some delay themselves (Outlook provides some outstanding examples of sluggishness: you see a new message, check it, and find out it has been received even a couple of *minutes* earlier. Especially true when your PC is old/busy/slow).

Comment: i don't care about how long it will take the email to get into the Receiver mailbox. it's the sending delay itself that I'm worried about, a delay the lead to a 5 minutes delay when pressing Enter to the time the function return.

Answer (score 1):

There are countless ways to deal with this problem but my approach has always been to have a completely different timed process or service that would read from the database directly and send emails independently from the ASP.NET application.

In an ideal large scale application you would use separate process with something like MSMQ - [Microsoft Message Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) on the receiving end.

**EDIT:**

OK, so there is another approach that is mentioned online in a couple of places (which I would strongly discourage using because it would be very brittle) but basically it involves creating an ASP.NET webservice that would contain your code to send the email and to invoke that service using jQuery. So what you would end up with is a webservice declared something like this

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class EmailSender : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void SendEmail(string email, string message)
    {
        //Send my email
    }
}
```

And on submission or form postback you would invoke it something along these lines.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    url: "EmailSender.asmx",
    data: JSON.stringify({ email: "mail@email.com",
        message: "this is a test message"
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //Do success stuff
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Do error stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: service is not an option at the moment, since my hosting plan is poor.

Comment: you mean to call a Generic Handler with jQuery OnComplete to send the email? i thought about it but it may be open for spammers...

Comment: Actually that could work too, and I agree it would be open to spammers but you don't seem to have much choice. Honestly I still suggest you look at upgrading your hosting rather than trying to work around this. The suggestion below isnt too bad either but depending on your hosting plan may also not be possible.

Comment: OK i will check for upgrades plans. meanwhile, is there a way to prevent spammers to abuse this SendMail method? is there a way to force calling this function only once on specific parameters? i guess i can do it with DB, but maybe there is an easier way to implement it differently? maybe by sending datetime value and allow running the function only within 2 seconds. or maybe other way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one project. My solution to that problem was to have a separate SMTP server running with a pickup location for my homepage to dump any emails that has to be sent. When doing this, creating emails is from the ASP .Net side instant. The SMTP server then handle the actual send procedure.

This made sure that my webpage responds quickly and that I don't send out so many emails in one go that my SMTP server gets blacklisted by other SMTP servers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpdeliverymethod.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this code, the SendMailMessageAsync() method. this is from BlogEngine's source code.

```
public static string SendMailMessage(MailMessage message)
{
    if (message == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("message");
    }

    StringBuilder errorMsg = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var smtp = new SmtpClient(Settings.Instance.SmtpServer);

        // don't send credentials if a server doesn't require it,
        // linux smtp servers don't like that 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Instance.SmtpUserName))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(yourusername, yourpassword));
        }

        smtp.Port = Settings.Instance.SmtpServerPort;
        smtp.EnableSsl = Settings.Instance.EnableSsl;
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMsg.Append("Error sending email in SendMailMessage: ");
        Exception current = ex;

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (errorMsg.Length > 0) { errorMsg.Append(" "); }
            errorMsg.Append(current.Message);
            current = current.InnerException;

            Logger.Error("Error sending email in SendMailMessage.", ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Remove the pointer to the message object so the GC can close the thread.
        message.Dispose();
    }

    return errorMsg.ToString();
}

public static void SendMailMessageAsync(MailMessage message)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { SendMailMessage(message); });
}
```